# RxJS de-nesting callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, rxjs, rxjs5

I want to do something like:

```
Rx.Observable.of(userToken)
    .flatMap(verifyToken)
    .flatMap(getUserInformation)
    .flatMap(createUser)
    .flatMap(signNewToken)
    .subcribe({
        next: result => useResult(result),
        error: error => handleError(error)
    })
```

What I'm trying to avoid is a callback mess. In my code, functions like `verifyToken` are Observables, and I want to chain them. Is this pattern on the right track? Because right now as soon as one of them internally does `observer.error(new Error('problem'))`, the chain crashes and my error handler is not called. How can I improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error does propagate to your subscriptions. This should simulate your situation:

```
const Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');
const Observable = Rx.Observable;

let userToken = Observable.of(42);
let verifyToken = Observable.range(1,3);
let getUserInformation = Observable.of('whatever');
let createUser = Observable.create(observer => {
    observer.error(new Error('problem'));
});

Observable.of(userToken)
    .flatMap(val => verifyToken)
    .flatMap(val => getUserInformation)
    .flatMap(val => createUser)
    .subscribe({
        next: result => console.log("Next:", result),
        error: error => console.log("Error subscriber:", error.message)
    });
```

The output in console is as expected:

```
Error subscriber: problem
```

Comment: you're right, this is absolutely working, it was a mistake on my part.  Thanks for making a minimum working example, which I should have done!